# Process how to show surjectivity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

> Let be $f:M\to N$ some function, where $M,N\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$. We have to check if $f$ is surjective.

We try to find out if all elements of $N$ possess a preimage but I am not sure how to describe this process mathematically.

Does this simply mean that we apply a finite number of not necessarily bijective functions $g_i$ to the equation $f(x)=y$ where each $g_i$ represents a transformation, e.g. taking the square, adding some other function etc... ?

So applying $h:=(g_n\circ g_{n-1}\circ\cdots g_1)$ to both sides of $f(x)=y$ yields
$$
h(f(x))=h(y)\implies x=h(y).
$$
If $h(y)\in M$ for all $y\in N$ then $f$ is surjective.

Is this correct? Maybe I am overthinking. How would you describe this process rigorously?

Comment: Without a further structure of $f$ being given, I think any discussion is not going to be helpful.

Comment: @Hermis14 why? Is it not possible to describe it in a general way?

Comment: Even for $n=1$, it may not be possible to carry out this program. E.g., $f(x)=x+\sin x$ is surjective. but the is no $h$ expressible in closed form such that $h(x+\sin x)=x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, ok then I should relax the statement to "if we are able to find such a function $h$".

Comment: Suppose $n=1$, $M$ is the nonnegative reals, $N$ is the reals, $f(x)=\sqrt x$, $h(y)=y^2$. Then all your conditions are satisfied, but $f$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very broad answer is "it depends".

Sometimes, we prove surjectivity the way you suggest, by finding some kind of pseudo-inverse of the function that directly links elements in the codomain back to the domain.

Other times, though, we have to resort to less direct means. This might be because the function doesn't invert nicely (for example, $x + \sin x$ as mentioned in the comments), or because we're not looking at a single function but instead trying to prove a result for some general class of functions.

In those cases, we might make an appeal to a property of the function - for example, if the function is continuous then you could use the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). Or you might be able to construct a proof by contradiction - assume the existence of a point in the codomain that isn't in the image of $f$, and show that this leads to an impossible conclusion.

Here's how you could prove that $f(x) = x + \sin \pi x$ is surjective over the reals:

First, we note that since $x$ and $\sin \pi x$ are both continuous, $f$ is also continuous. Further, if $x$ is an integer, then $\sin \pi x = 0$ and hence $f(x) = x$.

Consider $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $n = \lfloor y \rfloor$ be the floor of $y$, i.e. the largest integer less than or equal to $y$, so $n = f(n) \leq y < f(n + 1) = n + 1$. But by the intermediate value theorem, that means there must be an $x \in [n, n+1]$ such that $f(x) = y$, and hence $f$ is surjective.